# HTTP Rest API Pagination Power Automate Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I guess this question applies to both Power Automate and Logic Apps.  I'm querying an API that returns a number of pages.

The JSON output looks like this:

```
{
  "_results": [

    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }

  ],

  "pageNumber": 1,
  "totalPageCount": 5,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "pageCount": 100,
  "totalCount": 445,

}
```

I've omitted the results data to save space.

In this example, the API result shows the data for Page 1 and we also see that there are 5 pages in total.

I tried using the pagination setting in Logic Apps but I think that only applies to continuation tokens.

I would like to know how we can loop through the pages based on the logic of pageNumber <= totalPageCount ?

Thanks

Comment: Since it's an API request, you probably need to send inside the request the page you want do see as an argument.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt thus far? Control actions exist, it’s be nice to know what the specific issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to resolve this now. Here are the steps that I've created in the logic app:

- Parse JSON response from API call
- Initialize an integer variable (TotalPages) and assign it the totalPageCount item from the response
- Initialize an array variable (Pages) and assign it the expression:  range(1, variables('TotalPages')).
- Use a For Each function to loop through each item in the Pages array variable.
- Within the For Each there's another API call that uses the Current Item, from the For Each, for the pageNumber parameter.

Comment: Exactly …! See, you didn’t us. :-)